# Adding a bathroom fan (and speaker) to end line switch

Tags: electrical

My bathroom has one light fixture controlled by an end-line switch. I want to add a Delta Breez model VFB25ADBT ( *that also has a built-in Bluetooth speaker--nifty* ) and be able to control lights, fan, and speaker separately from the combination switch pictured.

The hot wire from the electrical panel comes into the light fixture, and there's also an additional run that leaves it and goes to lights/outlets elsewhere in the house.

I have a hunch I need to run some 14/3 but want confirmation before I spend a few hours fishing romex.

Any tips on how to wire all this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The bluetooth speaker does not need separate power/control. That should be provided for with the control unit of the fixture.  The model # of the fixture you have will help in providing and answer. What do you  mean "end of line switch" ?

Comment: Yes, can you provide a make/model for your fan unit please?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Added fan model number (Delta Breez VFB25ADBT) and wiring diagram to original post. The manual for the fan shows that the fan and speaker can be wired for two separate switches.

Comment: Where is the wiring that goes from the switch to the light?

Comment: @FreeMan I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Your diagram shows a cable running to the panel and another running to "other outlets". I presume that somewhere, there's a cable running from the switch to the fan. Is that switch on the "to panel" cable, the "other outlets" cable, or is there a 3rd cable running from the box to the switch? Maybe [edit] your post to provide a picture of the fixture box behind the current fan (without disconnecting anything!) with labels (in picture or added digitally) identifying the various cables running into/out of the box.

Comment: @FreeMan there was a 14/2 connecting the light fixture to a single pole, single throw switch. I want to replace that switch with a single pole, triple throw switch to control light, fan, and speaker.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you probably have a  switch leg going from the light to the switch (1 cable with a black and white possibly a ground. That cable the whit should be connected to the hot and the black to the hot for the light when the switch is turned on the black provides the power to the light. If I were making the change I would use “smurf tube” flexible nonmetallic conduit and make the following changes.

All the wires for the circuit have to be in the same cable or to have 3 switches you would need 3 cables , run conduit “smurf tube” and all the wires can be in that conduit.  You said 14 awg wire so I will assume you verified this is a 15 amp circuit. If it is a 20 amp circuit you would need 12 awg.

I would pull 1 black conductor for the feed to the 3 switches, 1 white conductor for the neutral (code requires the neutral even if not needed for future smart switches).
A ground wire only 1 is needed.
Last I would pull 3 red wires (you can use black just label them so you know 1,2,3). 
Cap the neutral it’s not needed, put the light on 1, fan on 2 and usb on 3 , connecting the devices in the attic with neutral.

Depending on what code version there may be a way to have a 2nd double switch leg using 14-3 but you need to bring the hot down in this cable also, and return the 2 switched hots and would not have the neutral , there are a few states on older code the only question would they allow this to 1 yoke (3 switches on 1 device it was ok with multi gang boxes and devices and how we did it sometimes prior to needing the neutral.

The first way is modern code the 2nd may be depending on your jurisdiction.